# How to return only digits from a scanned string? "incompatible types" error. java

Tags: java, incompatibility

I tried to compile my code, but I got an "incompatible error" with my last code (else if). I was trying to say in that code, "if the input was a mixture of digits and letters return only digits", but it's telling me that there is something wrong with what I have done, and I couldn't figure it out.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Pr8{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Prompt the user for how many numbers are going to be entered

    System.out.print("* Please write how many numbers are going to be entered: ");
      if (!scan.hasNextInt())
        System.out.println("- Sorry your entery was not correct. The compiler except's digits only.");

      else {
        int a = scan.nextInt(); //a is the scanned number of the user request
        int[] n = new int[a];   //is an array to declare a variable as much as the user entered
        int num = 1;            //to show the sorting number of the string when printing

        //prompt the user to enter a mixture of digits and letters

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
          System.out.print("* Please enter a string #" + num++ + ": ");
            if (scan.hasNextInt()){          //check if the input has only integers
              n[i] = scan.nextInt();
              System.out.println("- " + n[i] + " = " + n[i]);
            }//if
            else if (!scan.hasNextInt()){   //if the input was a mixture of digits and letters, return only the digits
              n[i] = scan.nextLine();
              System.out.println("- there is letters");
            }//else  
        }//for
      }//else if

  }//main
}//Pr8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User *Eran* ist right. Your program is a bit unclean anyway. I suggest you get rid of the comments and use variable names which tell the reader what they are supposed to contain. What you want is probably this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pr8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you wish to enter?  ");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.err.print("Again, how many numbers?  ");
            scanner.next();
        }
        int numberCount = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[numberCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++) {
            String numberString;
            System.out.print("Please enter string #" + (i + 1) + " containing a number:  ");
            scanner.nextLine();
            while ((numberString = scanner.findInLine("[+-]?[0-9]+")) == null) {
                System.err.print("Again, string #" + (i + 1) + " should contain a number:  ");
                scanner.nextLine();
            }
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
            System.out.println("Number #" + (i + 1) + " found = " + numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample console log:**

```
How many numbers do you wish to enter?  weewdfsa
Again, how many numbers?  324klj
Again, how many numbers?  5
Please enter string #1 containing a number:  23
Number #1 found = 23
Please enter string #2 containing a number:  sdfsdf
Again, string #2 should contain a number:  werq
Again, string #2 should contain a number:  sdf345df
Number #2 found = 345
Please enter string #3 containing a number:  -34ewr
Number #3 found = -34
Please enter string #4 containing a number:  wqweq+555
Number #4 found = 555
Please enter string #5 containing a number:  xxx-11yyy
Number #5 found = -11
```

Comment: can you please look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181778/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-50-handling-big-integers-on-java ///// the program I did is the 9's complement to deal with addition and subtraction in java, but there is some problems with it!!

Comment: Would you please accept and upvote this answer first so we can close one issue before switching to the next one?

Comment: But you can accept, because you asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

`n[i] = scan.nextLine();`

You are assigning a String to an int variable. You can't do that.

You should probably display an error message prompting the user to enter only digits. If you wish to display the invalid input to the user, store the `String` returned by `scan.nextLine()` in a `String` variable.

Comment: I know, but I was trying to tell the compiler that if the user entered a digit only print the digit. otherwise, if he printed a mixture of digits and letters return only the digits. how can I write that?

Comment: @Bader You'd probably need some regular expression, but it doesn't look like a good approach to me. Suppose that the user enters 1O7 by mistake instead of 107. You would treat it as 17 instead of informing the user about the error and asking for a valid input.

Comment: you are right. But, that is why I want to return the digits, so that the user will have the chance to review what numbers he entered.

Comment: do you have an idea what kind of expression it needs to do that?

Comment: Example of how the program should work:
How many numbers are going to be entered? 4 (By the user)
47ab3 = 473 ////
xxxA2zz = 2 ////
x1x2x0x = 120 ////
abcdefg1hijkl2MNOP = 12 ////

Comment: @Bader `n[i] = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine().replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""))`

Comment: it shows an error "NumberFormatException" when typing 93d8s

Comment: @Bader I just tried it and got 938. Are you sure you copied it right?

Comment: where did you past it?

Comment: @Bader I just put that line in a simple application that reads a line with Scanner.nextLine(), and entered 93d8s. `     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int num = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine ().replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""));
     System.out.println (num);`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example to filter numbers from string..code is bit messy...hope you can get the idea.

```
package strings;
public class ScanNumbersOnly {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        int i=0,k=0,counter=0;
        String input="4 h5i dhfg 454hdkjfg dkjfhg iudhfg";
        System.out.println("String="+input);
        String spaceRemover[]=input.split(" ");
        for(String s:spaceRemover){
            builder.append(s);
        }
        input=builder.toString();

        char stringTocharacter[]=input.toCharArray();
        int stringarray[]=new int[stringTocharacter.length];
        for(char s:stringTocharacter){
            int charTonumericvalue=Character.getNumericValue(s);
            if(charTonumericvalue<=9){
                stringarray[i]=charTonumericvalue;
                counter++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        int finallist[]=new int[counter];
        for(int s:stringarray){
            if(s>0){
                finallist[k]=s;
                k++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("After filtiring string=");
        for(int numberextractor:finallist){
            System.out.print(numberextractor);
        }

    }
}
```